# MongoDB javascript query; filter for value in in a column array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Using vanilla javascript, I'm using Mongo's dpd.js for querying the db.

In this snippet, I am trying find all matches for `"design"` in the column `roleConsiderations` within the collection `techniques`.

The values in `roleConsiderations` are in arrays - `["development", "design", "content"]` and all of my different attempt to query for `"design"` fails.

dpd.js query results in empty response:

```
var query = {"roleConsiderations": "design"};
dpd.techniques.get(query, function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Attempting to query through the url only returns exact matches (where `"design"` is the only value in the array).

```
http://my.mongo.db/techniques?roleConsiderations=["design"]
```

So how to query a mongodb column filtering for a value in an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **$in** operator to specify the elements you want the returned objects to contain in specified field.

```
const query = { roleConsiderations: { $in: [ 'design' ] } };
```

Horrible syntax, I know, but it should work.

For more reading, please refer to [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in).

Comment: Revised last comment. This worked perfectly. Thanks.